# Representing Timed Events

Tags: python, events

I am doing lots of test automation with a variety of operating systems. I am trying to execute different workloads and actions for the different tests. For instances, I'll have a test that has at some time (t0) an event to install an application, time (t1) search for an update, time (t2) install the update. I was wondering if there was a good tool to help represent and sequence the events? Is there a programing model that would help me represent these events?

Thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: Are you looking for a scheduling library (to run the events at the times you specify), or do you want to monitor when the events are running and their time deltas?

Comment: I would like a scheduling library .